# Jre not working in Fedora

Tags: java, firefox, applet, fedora

I am having trouble getting my jre to work. I have uninstalled and reinstalled it several times but that is not working. I have setup the firefox symlink.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/java/jre1.7.0_21/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so
```

I have tried to follow these instructions.

http://www.mjmwired.net/resources/mjm-fedora-f19.html#java

I have checked here several times. The box just stays grey and nothing happens.

https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre

I have tried in Firefox, Chrome, and Seamonkey. It is not working in any of the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The Java plugin and Firefox must match the build platform (i.e. both have to be 32 OR 64 bits). Check that.

Comment: It does. It had been working fine for several months and today it magically stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox disables certain plugins for security reasons, [one of them is the Java plugin](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-to-enable-java-if-its-been-blocked). Check in the add-ons menu whether the plugin is enabled or not.

Comment: I have tried in Firefox, Chrome, and Seamonkey. It is not working in any of the browsers.

Comment: @cokedude I'm using fedora 19 and firefox too. I noticed that the java detection thingy indeed stays grey. Other applets ([such as these](http://donar.umiacs.umd.edu/quadtree/)) did work, however. Could you try if you can run any other applets, maybe there's just something wrong with the detection thingy?